# Grafana not sharing dashboards in High Availability mode

Tags: mariadb, grafana

I am trying to set Grafana (version 9.5.5, SUSE Linux) to high availability mode using MariaDB on an external server.  My understanding is that this should result in my multiple Grafana instances sharing dashboards (create on one, visible on another).  I can get them to connect, but not share dashboards.
Note: I'm new to both Grafana config and database use.

I setup MariaDB with the below commands (note for privacy I will use example passwords and IPS):

On MariaDB server:

`mysql -u root -p`

`create database grafana;`

`grant all privileges on grafana.* TO 'grafanareader' identified by "PWORD";`

On the two Grafana servers:

`nano /usr/share/grafana/conf/defaults.ini`

```
type = sqlite3
host = 123.45.678.99 (my MariaDB host IP) 
name = grafana
user = grafanareader

password = PWORD
```

(note, I don't know if this is relevant or not, but when I try and set that to mysql instead of sqlite3, it won't start the service)

`systemctl restart grafana-server.service`
(no error, it parses the ini and runs)

Confirmed that these settings reflect in the Administration-Settings section of the GUI.

Test 1: Log into GUI, go to Menu-DataSources-Add New-Mysql-put in same parameters as above-save and test=**test successful**

Test 2: Using that new datasource, through GUI access a manually created table in database=**test successful**

(the above two tests are just meant to show that the problem is not in a failed connection or failure of the user to access the database)

Test 3: Create a dashboard on Grafana server 1.  Check to see if dashboard has properly replicated to Grafana server 2. = ***Test failed***

So, am I misunderstanding high availability mode?  Is it just not possible for Grafana so share dashboards between instances?  Or have I configured something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, DO NOT EVER alter `/usr` (except `/usr/local`) unless you know what you're doing. `/usr` is the package manager's domain.

From the [Grafana documentation](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/) (which I highly recommend you read given you're unfamiliar with it):

> The default settings for a Grafana instance are stored in the `$WORKING_DIR/conf/defaults.ini` file. *Do not* change this file.
>
> [...]
>
> If you installed Grafana using the `deb` or `rpm` packages, then your configuration file is located at `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` and a separate `custom.ini` is not used. This path is specified in the Grafana init.d script using `--config` file parameter.

Stil from the [Grafana configuration](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#database):

> Grafana needs a database to store users and dashboards (and other things). By default it is configured to use `sqlite3` which is an embedded database (included in the main Grafana binary).
>
> **type**
>
> Either `mysql`, `postgres` or `sqlite3`, it’s your choice.

Unless you actually instruct Grafana to use something other than SQLite, it will ignore all parameters not relevant to it. If it doesn't start when you change it, that's you're issue which you need to debug.

Comment: Given that a shared functional external sqlite3 database would, by nature, result in shared dashboards, I do not see the logic of your answer. Making the assumption that you have personally created a working example of this in the past and are not just guessing, would you be so kind as to share an example of a functional ini for High Availability mode?

Comment: Again, [Grafana high availability](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/set-up-for-high-availability/) clearly documents that the "shared database can be either MySQL or Postgres". SQLite3 isn't particularly designed for concurrent access which makes it unsuitable for the job. I'll give pointers but I don't do homework, if that's what you're looking for, hire a consultant.

Comment: Yes I must admit you were right.  When I switched to using the /etc/grafana/grafana.ini file, I was able to get it working with mysql with a few tweaks.  Though it did require adding a "Session" section with a provider and provider config, which the docs don't mention.

Comment: @CaptainSkyfish can you please explain what do you mean by `Session` section? And what you added to it for reference?

Comment: @mrid I will share as much as the comments box allows: In /etc/grafana/grafana.ini the documentation says you need either the database section (like I have above) OR the session section, I found both were required.  Note that my original database provider field was incorrect.  And of course, your ini file location may vary, but it will not work with defaults.ini
###SESSION###
[session]
provider = mysql
provider_config = `grafanareader:PWORD@tcp(123.45.678.99:3306)/grafana`